# Validate against API connection error

Tags: php, api

I have a code to connect to an API that looks like this:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url . $guid . $api_key);
$response = json_decode($api_user);
```

But sometimes the API is not available, and the scrip throws errors. How can I validate to check if the request was successful?

I have tried:

```
if($response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $guid . $api_key))) {
  // success
}
```

But I still get the  "Warning: file_get_contents...failed to open stream: HTTP request failed" error.

The URL, GUID and APIKEY are correct, and usually it does work fine. But when it doesn't I just get the error report.

Comment: Turn off error reporting for production environments. `file_get_contents()` should still be returning false and you should be able to check for that

Comment: Hmmm, but switching reposrting off, would just hide the fact that an error is occurring. There must be a way to validate so that the error doesn't occur at the first place.

Comment: Sure there is - as said, check what the result of the file_get_contents() is. If it is false, the call failed.